# Postgres indexing a byte array column vs varchar

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a need to perform duplicate checks before inserting a record. The parameter to be used for this check is a string. This string is of no fixed length (we expect this to keep growing). So we have the following options

1. Store this string directly and index it and use it in the where clause.
2. Hash this string and store it after converting the byte array to a string and index it.
3. Store the byte array as it is and index it.

What would be the best solution? Please suggest.

Comment: There is no good solution. Index entries are quite limited in size, and using a hash there could be false positive collisions. What you'd need is a collision-free hash, but I believe that is a hard problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, thanks for the reply. We are planning on using SHA-512 which has a  very low hash collision. Do you think this would cause an issue?

Comment: Perhaps not, but what do you do if you happen to have a collision?